# Basic find replace words

Tags: javascript

All I want is to replace several words to other words. I tried the following but it conflicts and breaks other elements of the site such as AJAX elements etc.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/searchword/g, "resultword");
```

I'm also pretty sure this is a fairly non-elegant way to do this when just doing this for multiple words in a big list. Thanks.

Comment: What are *AJAX elements*? How exactly does it break the page?

Comment: @Felix: It destroys the DOM and all event handlers.

Comment: @SLaks: Right, forgot about the event handlers...

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, it disables in page pop-ups, showing/collapsing tables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting at the parent element that contains all the text you are searching (up to the body), replace the text in each text node.

If you have a huge page with many replacements you may need to break it up with a timer, or hide the parent element until all the replacements are done. Otherwise you will get a page redraw for every change.

```
function replaceText(node, find, rep){
    if(node){
        node= node.firstChild;
        while(node!= null){
            if(node.nodeType== 3){
                node.data= node.data.replace(find, rep);
            }
            else{
                if(node.hasChildNodes()) replaceText(node, find, rep);
            }
            node= node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

replaceText(document.body,/e/g,'E')

Comment: looks like I celebrated just to fast, I just did a quick check before. Problem is that the text I which to replace has a line break in the middle. With the `document.body.innerHTML.replace` it worked by using: `/first_line<br>\nsecond_line/g, "result")` with this that doesn't work anymore. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following example

[Recursively Loop Through All Nodes](http://blog.dingoeweb.com/javascript/recursive-iteration-through-the-html-dom)

and then check its `nodeType`. If its == 3 it means its a text node, then just do a replace on the `nodeValue` of the node.